# how to add version of style.css in wordpress

Tags: themes, css

How to add version of `style.css` in WordPress like below i can do in Joomla.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/example/css/style.css?v=1.2">
```

i know that the `style.css` will load dynamically. please help me to how to do that.

Comment: Here is a plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-css-version-history/ that will automatically append a version number in the stylesheet. It creates a new stylesheet which is loaded last. No need to clear cache to see changes. Uses Wordpress built in CSS editor and user file lock for team collaboration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Version number is a parameter of [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

As per the Codex, here are all the parameters that `wp_enqueue_style` accepts.

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

So for example to load a stylesheet with a version number you'd do the following:

```
function wpa_90820() {
    wp_enqueue_style('my-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/my-styles.css', array(), '1.0' );       
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_90820');
```

Comment: when i do this the old style.css is also loading. How to remove it?

Comment: @VinodDalvi what do you mean by handle. i don't know about it ,i m new to wordpress please me.

Comment: @Toretto Either you theme is hard-coding it in header.php or your theme is also enqueing it with a different handle (the first parameter).  The solution also depends on if you are directly editing your theme's functions.php or if you've created a child theme.

Comment: @Toretto, $handle is shown in my response and also described in the link I provided to the Codex page for `wp_enqueue_style` please do your homework.

Comment: @helgatheviking how can i know the old handler name.

Comment: @Toretto If your theme is using `wp_enqueue_style()` to load the stylesheet in question then it's handle is the *first* parameter.  If your theme is hard-coding the stylesheet in header.php then it won't have a handle.

Comment: ok i got it, i have replace my default theme style function and it start working.thanks a lot @helgatheviking.

Answer (score 20):

If you are a theme developer, you might want to force reload of your assets when you push new version.

So versioning of a theme is done in `style.css`

```
/*
    Theme Name: Your Theme Name
    Version: 1.0.2
*/
```

At the top of your `functions.php`:

```
$theme = wp_get_theme();
define('THEME_VERSION', $theme->Version); //gets version written in your style.css
```

Later when you enqueue CSS or JS, use `THEME_VERSION` as fourth argument:

```
function theme_styles()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main.css', [], THEME_VERSION, 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Will output to the page:

```
.../your-theme-name/css/main.css?ver=1.0.2
```

Gets handy when you have more assets to care about and don't want to change them manually.

Comment: I used this method for a child theme, so we used get_stylesheet_directory_uri() insted of get_template_directory_uri()

Answer (score 14):

Instead of hardwiring the version, you might find it better in some instances to dynamically version your stylesheet so whenever you change it, it automatically changes and refreshes the browser cache immediately without having to edit your functions.php over and over again.

You can use filemtime() to do that.  Here is how to do that in a child-style that references the parent_style

```
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( $parent_style ), filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' )  );
```

Comment: Over time, I've come to prefer theme versions, but it's a great idea to use filemtime() here, if one doesn't have a consistent theme versioning practice.

Comment: This is a great solution! I just used `array()` for the third parameter because I'm using a custom theme with no parent and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I think this is a good solution, you can still use something like "1.2.0" in your style.css it's not necessary to show this in the DOM where the CSS is loaded.

Comment: This is amazing, works like a charm!! Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using one of the following ways :

1) Add following tag in header.php file of the theme.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>'?v=1.2" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

2) Add following code in functions.php file of the theme.

```
function theme_styles()  
{ 
  // Register the style like this for a theme:  
  // (First the unique name for the style (custom-style) then the src, 
  // then dependencies and ver no. and media type)
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.2', 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

For more information see [this page.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: when i do this the old style.css is also loading. How to remove it?

Comment: What is the handle of old style.css?

Comment: if you are not able to find the handle then just copy and paste the whole style.css url here.. i will get it from there...

Comment: Or can you tell me whats your theme name or theme's folder name?

Comment: ok i got it, i have replace my default theme style function and it start working.thanks.+1 from me.

Comment: Welcome .... :)

Answer (score 2):

the best way to load css into your wordpress theme is the following code in your functions.php file:

```
function theme_styles()  
{ 
  global $ver_num; // define global variable for the version number
  $ver_num = mt_rand() // on each call/load of the style the $ver_num will get different value
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), $ver_num, 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

This is the right way to load the styles in your theme and also it's the best for staging/testing purposes because each refresh will deliver the updated version of the style.

If you want to avoid the loading 1st way, you can use this shorted version and place the following line into your header.php file and will get the same result:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); echo '?ver=' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add this to functions.php

```
function autoVer($filename){
    $url = get_template_directory_uri() . $filename;
    $file = get_template_directory() . $filename;
    if ( file_exists($file)) {
        return $url . '?v=' .md5(date("FLdHis", filectime($file)) . filesize($file));
    }
    clearstatcache();
}
```

Add this to the header or footer -> autoVer('/js/main.js');

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the methods presented so far, I believe it is better to use the version number which appears at the top of your style.css file:

```
// style.css
/**
Theme Name: My theme
...
Version: 1.2.3
...
**/
```

To use the theme's version in your css, add the following to your functions.php (or equivalent) script:

```
<?php

wp_enqueue_style(
    'my-theme',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    [],
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
```

This means that, after you edit your style.css file, all you need to do is to change the version number at the top of the same file to see the changes in the frontend.

If you examine the head section of the theme's HTML you will see the following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet'
    id='my-theme-css'
    href='... style.css?ver=1.2.3'
    type='text/css'
    media='all'
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you can't figure it out yet, it's to change the filename of your child theme's style.css to, for example, style2.css and then change it on your child theme's functions.php file, as shown below:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style2.css' );
```

This will cause Wordpress to request and serve a new CSS file for your website.

Answer (score 0):

Here we use WordPress’ wp_get_theme() to get the theme version (as specified in the theme’s stylesheet, style.css):

```php
// get theme version
function rave_get_version() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    return $theme_data->Version;
}
$theme_version = rave_get_version();
global $theme_version;

wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css', [], THEME_VERSION, 'all' );
```

Comment: I don't think that answers the question though which was how to add the version number to the CSS URL, for cache-busting I assume.

Comment: wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/css/style.css', [], THEME_VERSION, 'all' );

Answer (score 0):

You don't need in fact to un cache the style.css file.

You can write your own css file then queue like the way @vinod dalvi
has written.

```
function theme_styles()  
{ 
  wp_enqueue_style('stylecss',get_template_directory_uri().'/yourname.css', array(), '1.2', 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');
```

Based on browser rules the latest css file has higher priority , so make sure to use !important in your css code if necessary .

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty straight up way of getting the version number by calling the [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) `bloginfo($show)` twice. First for the stylesheet and secondly for the version number.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style-css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>?ver=<?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Thats all there is to it. Hope that helps or is useful. You can go through all the parameters available and see what you can output with the `bloginfo()` function.

**Ignore my comment since @Ravs has pointed out my error regarding the 'versions' parameter for the bloginfo() function. It does indeed print the Wordpress version number.**

Comment: I think that it is not correct answer because <?php bloginfo('version')?> gives you current wordpress version while question is  about append style.css version not wordpress version.